# How to use ECSlidingViewController in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, categories, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm trying to use **ecslidingviewcontroller** in my swift project but don't know how to proceed. I know about **bridging headers** in swift, and have imported `ECSlidingViewController.h` in my project.

*How to call methods or use this in my project?*

I'm trying to do something like `self.slidingViewController` property but getting error "value of type viewController has no member 'slidingviewcontroller' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed the issue.
In case we need to use any thing from category, we need to import that as well in our bridging header. `slidingViewController` is a property of category named as `UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController`.

I imported **UIViewController+ECSlidingViewController** in my bridging header and now i can use the property.

Answer (score 0):

Through Mix & Match ECSlidingViewController can be implement in Swift. I have implemented this and it's working fine.